# Static variable vs argument passing

Tags: architecture, static, structure, argument-passing

Couldn't phrase this into a proper title, sorry.
I'm wondering what the benefit is of a static field vs an argument that you keep passing until it reaches it's destination.

Example:

Xna uses GameTime in their framework, which is kept being passed into child functions in the Update function

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);
        world.Update(gameTime);
    }

    //in World class
    public void Update(GameTime gametime)
    {
        //draw all game objects
        for (int i = 0; i < entities.Count; i++)
        {
            entities[i].Update(gametime);
        }
    }
```

Is there any benefit to doing this, as opposed to keeping a static variable gametime somewhere, updating that in the root class before anything else and access that static variable from the child classes.

I always see the argument passing being used in libraries. But it seems so much more "convenient" to just have it static somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This static field is shared with all instances of the class. Static and mutable provide a dangerous mixture unless it's carefully controlled.  You don't want just anyone reaching out and touching that field unless it is essential that ALL instances need the change.

Answer (score 0):

And your method can be tested easier when you inject parameters. You could for example have a fake GameTime object which you could pass in to simulate it's behavior.